# Checking the heads of lists of lists

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I'm trying to write a function that filters on a list of lists however I can't manage to work out how. My first question of course is how to filter a list of lists

```
[[2,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,2,3]]
filter (==2)
```

The second thing I'm trying to work out is how to only filter the Head of each of the lists.

Eg for the above filter, I would expect an output of 2 from the first list, and 2 from the third list.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: This is very unclear: `map (filter (==2))` fits the description, yet you might be looking for something different. You should add some examples of expected input/output, at least.

Comment: Ah excellent that does work for my first problem- give me 2 seconds and I'll edit the question for expected output!

Comment: Still unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `filter (==2) $ map (head) [[2,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,2,3]]` ? But still the problem is very ambiguously stated.

Output:
`[2,2]`

EDIT:
As Thomas M. DuBuisson said head returns error when the list is empty according to its definition:

```
badHead :: a
badHead = errorEmptyList "head"

head []                 =  badHead
```

whereas `take !_  []     = []`.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm after- sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: This will fail if there is an empty list.  Might I suggest `filter (==2)  . concatMap (take 1)`.